# How does React.js + middleman work for caching and SEO?

Tags: javascript, caching, static, reactjs, middleman

I have been exploring react.js lately and using it in combination with middleman. I really like middleman because it serves up static assets that are easy and fast to host. It also allows you to just cache the entire page as well.

Now my ideal goal is to have the user come to my site, serve up the static assets and then have react populate the dynamic data. This seems great but then SEO becomes a problem. Fortunately react comes with server side rendering, but it's not entirely clear how it works in relation to page caching.

So from my current understanding when the server gets hit with react, it only creates a string of the html with the initialize data put into. Generally from examples the data populated is empty. It then gets recalled when the client hits and fills in the api based data and populates the html. Although I don't understand how this is SEO friendly, apparently it is.

Then I realized that I should be able to still cache the entire instance that react creates with the string, serve that up, and then react can still populate it while being seo friendly. Does this work like I want it to or where in the react lifecycle does this not work?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can absolutely cache the generated markup string.

The only thing you need to be careful of is that the props you pass on the server should match the props you pass on the client exactly, so that the initial rendered markup matches, or else React is forced to throw away the server-rendered markup and start from scratch. (The development/uncompressed version of React will give you a warning if the markup doesn't match.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I was scouring the internet to find this answer. Not nearly enough community docs yet.